# Jquery - Only the first data hid in the div element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to Jquery and currently encountering an issue in my code. I need to hide an asterisk whenever the html form loaded. However, only the first asterisk hid. The TD tag is inside a for loop statement

HTML Code:

```
<td style="..." rowspan="0">
   <div id="divhasvalue">
   <label style="...">*</label>
   </div>
</td>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divhasvalue").hide();
});
```

Output in the Form:
[image]

Comment: You need to post a full working snippet

Comment: It's difficult to tell why the other ones aren't working when you don't show us the code for them! However I suspect that you are replicating the code above for each one, including the id. However ids must be unique. Either use a class or give each element a unique id.

Comment: IDs must be unique.  Many functions assume this, such as `$("#id")` will assume you only have 1 element with ID=id so will only return one element, the first one.   Use classes, not IDs.

Comment: Guys. I forgot that. It should be class instead of an ID. now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the class instead of id. Give the same class to the divs you want to hide